# Arabic data with jQuery-ajax and Servlets

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets, character-encoding

actually i'm trying to send Arabic data using jQuery ajax to Servlet

but when i try to reprint these data on the page it is displayed like

Ø¨Ø±ÙØ¬Ø©

and this is my jQuery ajax code

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/SearchedCoursesGetter",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {
                'searchKey':  'حديث'
            },
            success: function( data ) {
               document.write(data);
                }));
            }
        });
```

and this is the code in java servlet

```
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print( request.getParameter("searchKey"));
```

any body can help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the top of your JSP

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

This will implicitly do `response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8")` and `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` on the JSP itself. This way the browser will interpret the document (and thus also all JS on it) as UTF-8.

You also need to ensure that your JSP/JS files are saved as UTF-8. Check the editor settings and/or *Save As* option, depending on the editor used.

Note that the `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` has only effect on POST requests, not on GET requests. For GET requests you need to configure it at servletcontainer level. In for example Tomcat, you need to add `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute to the `<Connector>` in `/conf/server.xml`.

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: All these options are handled correctly and the problem still doesn't solved :S

Comment: I realized that `jQuery.ajax()` defaults to GET. So the parameter ends up in request URI instead of request body. You need to configure the servletcontainer to interpret URI as UTF-8 as well. See updated answer (this is by the way also mentioned in the "See also" link).

Comment: yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssss, thanks alot, that's it

Tomcat, you need to add URIEncoding="UTF-8" attribute to the <Connector> in /conf/server.xml.